# Fixed shipping rates by quantity and product type

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping

A client of mine is interested in calculating shipping using fixed prices. These prices change by product type and quantity.

For example:

**Clothing**

```
| Quantity | Shipping Amount |
|----------|-----------------|
| 1        | $3              |
| 2        | $5              |
| 3        | $7              |
| 4        | $8              |
| 5        | $9              |
```

**Misc. Products**

```
| Quantity | Shipping Amount |
|----------|-----------------|
| 1        | $2              |
| 2        | $4              |
| 3        | $6              |
| 4        | $7              |
| 5        | $9              |
```

1x clothing + 2x misc. items = $3 + $4 = $7 (total shipping)

### Achieving this is Magento 2

Before building this as a custom module, or purchasing an existing module, I would like to know if this is possible in the out-of-the-box Magento 2.1 platform. Table rates appear to be the closest match to the functionality I'm after, but the conditions assume the calculations are affected by destination.

#### Purchase a Module

I've identified several "advanced shipping" modules. Some allow pricing by attribute, which is an almost-solution. Are there any known modules that I may have overlooked, which can achieve what I'm looking for?

#### Custom Module

My initial thoughts are to create a rate management module where my client may enter a list of quantities and their corresponding rates, then assign those rates to a value of a custom attribute. A default set of rates would be used if a product does not contain the custom shipping attribute.

Ideally, I would prefer to avoid building a new module if an existing solution is available. I'm looking for recommendations from developers who have more experience with the Magento 2.* platform.

thank you

Comment: I created the similar module, and this is not easy. If you wish to develop an own one [here](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/) you can find some information about how to develop module with conditions. In my case all rules are based on the conditions and on a valid items, then actions is applying one by one, like shipping surcharge per 1 kg or per valid items qty (as in your example). If you want to purchase the already developed module, you can look [here](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/06/magento-2-shipping-rules-explained/) how it works.